# How to get file size before downloading from url?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alert

I trying to show file size before downloading in my `AlertView` after cell click:

```
var fileSize = 0

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let url = URL(string: "http://ex.com/\(indexPath.row).mp3")!
    getDownloadSize(url: url, completion: { (size, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("An error occurred when retrieving the download size: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("The download size is \(size).")
        self.fileSize = Int(size)
        }
    })

    // Create the alert controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Size - \(self.fileSize) MB", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

    etc

}

func getDownloadSize(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Int64, Error?) -> Void) {
        let timeoutInterval = 5.0
        var request = URLRequest(url: url,
                                 cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
                                 timeoutInterval: timeoutInterval)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            let contentLength = response?.expectedContentLength ?? NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown
            completion(contentLength, error)
        }.resume()
    }
```

But when I click on cell first time I get Size - 0 MB. And if I click next time on any cell I get size from previous url(previous cell). How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL data task is asynchronous. Your code is not waiting until it has completed before displaying the dialog.

It's like sending somebody to the garden to count how many apples he sees lying on the ground, so you can put that number onto a piece of paper. You tell that person to go counting and put the result into a box, where currently the number zero is stored. As soon as the person leaves, you are opening the box and writing down the number you see. Yet the person hasn't even arrived in the garden, nor has the person counted any apples yet. When the person returns, he does as you told him, put the number of counted apples in the box. Now you send the person again, this time counting the numbers or pears he can see in the garden. And again, as soon as the person left, you open up the box and write down the number you see there, but that is still the number from counting apples as the person didn't even have a chance to update that number.

The block you feed to `getDownloadSize()` will run once the result has been fetched, but the code below that call runs immediately after calling `getDownloadSize()`, it will not wait until the block has executed.

And it wouldn't be a good idea to change that since fetching the result can take anything from a few seconds to several minutes. If the execution of code would block until the result has been fetched, your entire application would block for that time as well (your UI would completely freeze, no user interaction would be possible).

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the filesize in the didSelectRowAt method, which only gets called when you select the row.  You should lazy load a variable in the cell in the cellForRowAt method instead.  But be careful to not do the download on the main thread.